# How to replace sqlDMO with SQLSMO in c++

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, c++-cli

Is Managed code is the only way to use sqlsmo.

Can ay body help me

Answer (score 1):

SMO is strictly written for use in managed code from everything I have ever read.  As per the following BOL Entry:

[SMO Programming Languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162558.aspx)

> SMO is a .NET assembly. To program by
> using the Microsoft .NET Framework,
> you must choose a language that is
> supported by the common language
> runtime. In the SMO reference, there
> is syntax for managed languages such
> as Visual Basic .NET and Visual C#
> .NET.